# Stylus global variables

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, middleware, stylus, file-structure

I have a **core.styl** where I put my grid-style, some stylus-functions and some variables. This file should be imported in **all** of my routes.

Beside that I have an page.styl which depends on my current route (e.g. **contact.styl** for /contact)

Note: My project is based on angular.js so the html-head doesn't reload. But I'm able to add some stuff with angular in html-head like `<link href="contact.css">`.

I tried following

```html
//index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.css" /> <-- this is static, always there
                               
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pages/contact.css" /> <-- added by angular
```

The Problem:
In the contact.styl I have **no access** to my stylus variables and functions (declared in core.styl)

one solution: `@import '../core.styl'` in each page stylesheet. But for me out of the question.

Is there an other solution I can try out?

Maybe something like that (server.js)?

```js
function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .import(config.path_client + "/css/core")
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true);
}
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: config.path_client + '/css/pages',
    compile: compile
}));
```

(tried very long but still doesn't work for me)

Edit: My file structure:

```
|client
||css
|||pages
||||-contact.styl
||||-contact.css
|||base
||||-core.styl
||||-core.css
|server
||-server.js
|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS API and define these vars using `define` method. See http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html#definename-node

Comment: isnt that finally the same as the first solution i mentioned where i did '@'import 'core.styl' ? Or maybe i dont get it right so if correct me please: I do .set('filename', '/myvars.styl').define(myvars) and then do '@'import 'myvars.styl' OR I do  .set('filename', path).define(myvars) that myvars are directly imported in e.g. contact.css. So both end up the same that myvars are on top of e.g. contact.styl file defined or? --is there no way to define this vars completely independend of any .styl/.css file?

Comment: From your question it seems like exactly what you need (the defined global vars and functions will be accessible inside `contact.styl` without importing them in the `core.styl`.

Comment: They will be completely independent (they're just globals).

Comment: ok thanks it works great for me :) now i must find a way to define all of my vars and fns in a overseeable way ..maybe a .json file

Comment: so finally i have mutch more than just a few vars and functions ..and i use jeet (set of functions)   is there a way to define this functions all at once? something like that .define(allmyfunction.styl) ?

Comment: You can use `import` method (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html#importpath)

Comment: Also you can write a complete plugin and use `use` method (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html#usefn)

Comment: prefer the plugin ..so i have to write a js-function that wrapps all my stylus functions/vars automatically in a `define()` block (maybe store them before in a json file) ?